# Wall Painting Calculator. (two solutions - giving two different results)

Tags: java

A while ago I started to learn JAVA and everything was going well, until I got to this exercise:

### CONDITIONS

Write a program that when complete will calculate the amount of paint needed to paint the walls and the ceiling of a room.

Your program should ask the length, width, and height of the room. Assume that the room has doors and windows the don't need painting. Also, the floor in the room is not painted.

Ask the user to enter the number of doors and number of windows in the room, and adjust the total square feet to be painted accordingly.

Assume that each door is 20 square feet and each window is 15 square feet.
Suppose the paint covers 350 square feet per gallon. enter code here

#### My chosen parameters

```
Width    3;
Length  10;
Height   2.0;
Doors    1;
Windows  2;
```

#### MY SOLUTION

```
int width     = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please, enter the width of a room"));
int length    = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please, enter the length of the room"));
double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please, enter the height of the room"));
int doors     = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("If there are doors, please, enter the amount of them:"));
int windows   = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("If there are some windows, please, enter the amount of them:"));

double feet   = 1.00/350.00;
double area   = (width*length*height)-(windows*15+doors*20);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You need:"+feet*area+" gallons of paint.");
```

}
}

The output is `0.02857142`

#### OTHER SOLUTIONby the author of the exercise

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        {
        int length, width, numberOfDoors, numberOfWindows;
        double height;
        
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter length: ");
        length = console.nextInt();
 
        System.out.print("Enter width: ");
        width = console.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter height: ");
        height = console.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("Enter number of doors: ");
        numberOfDoors = console.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter number of windows: ");
        numberOfWindows = console.nextInt();

        double totalSurfaceArea = 2 * (length * width + length
                * height + width * height);

        int areaOfFloor = length * width;
        
        int areaOfDoors = 20 * numberOfDoors;
        
        int areaOfWindows = 15 * numberOfWindows;
        
        double totalPaintArea = totalSurfaceArea - areaOfFloor
                - areaOfDoors - areaOfWindows;
        
        double requiredPaint = totalPaintArea / 350;

        System.out.println("Paint required "
                + requiredPaint + " gallons.");
      }
      }
      }
        The output is 0.09142857142857143;
```

So, two different solutions gave two different outputs.

Is there anyone who could help me to clarify, where I went wrong?

Comment: For one, `width*length*height` calculates the volume, not the surface area, of the room.

Comment: For two, this is a great opportunity to play with a debugger and look into the variables at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, the only thing I needed to do was to write a correct function to calculate a surface area. I felt it was a silly question, anyway, TY for your help. :)